# How to Safely Quote an Arbitrary String in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsqldeveloper

I need to quote the following text as demontrated on the follwoing simplified example

From:

```
SELECT LISTAGG(nvl(phone_number,''), ';') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY employee_id) 
"Department''s phone numbers"
FROM   employees
where  department_id = 20
```

To:

```
'SELECT LISTAGG(nvl(phone_number,''''), '';'') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY 
employee_id) "Department''''s phone numbers"
FROM   employees
where  department_id = 20'
```

Note that the quotes in the string must be duplicated.

I need this in order to include the actual query in an insert statement. I have to do this manually as I have several and quite large SQL queries.

I have no restriction how to do it. It need not be done with SQL;  Notepad++ or other are fine as well.

Comment: it seems a regex replace could do this

Comment: The only workaround that I've found in SQL Developer, without actually writing that regexp, was to:
1. create a dummy table, with one column, varchar2(4000)
2. insert the string
3. export -> Format: Insert
4. delete extra generated text that is not of interest to the current issue

Comment: Are you only looing for solutions with especially `' '` (quotes) or anything else ?

Comment: Please provide a real example, i.e. the original string and the target insert string. Do you know the [Q quoted strings](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=311), they were invented to *eliminate the need of duplicating the quotes in the string*.

Comment: @MarmiteBomber Quoted strings solved my requirement.

Comment: Found an [Online converter](https://sql-tuning.com/convert-static-sql-to-dynamic-sql/) as well.

Comment: Glad to hear and you learned, next time ask problems not tools;)